# How to optimise grunt configuration

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, config

I am setting up some [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) tasks using [grunt-vagrnat-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-vagrant-ssh) plugin.

I would like to avoid some unnecessary number of duplications in the provided sample configuration. More specifically I'm talking about **path** , **flags** and even maybe the **callback** fields.

Is there any chance that I could defined them once for all of my tasks and shell commands?

Basically to change the following

```
grunt.initConfig({
    vagrantssh: {
        addfile: {
            path: './.vvv/',
            commands: [
                'echo "testing" > /tmp/test.txt',
                'cat /tmp/test.txt'
            ],
            flags: [ '-t', '-A' ],
            callback: function( grunt, output ) {
                grunt.log.writeln( 'Output: ' + output );
            }
        },
        removefile: {
            path: './.vvv/',
            commands: [
                'rm -rf /tmp/test.txt',
                'cat /tmp/test.txt'
            ],
            flags: [ '-t', '-A' ],
            callback: function( grunt, output ) {
                grunt.log.writeln( 'Output: ' + output );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

to something like

```
grunt.initConfig({
    vagrantssh: {
        options: {
            path: './.vvv/',
            flags: [ '-t', '-A' ],
            callback: function( grunt, output ) {
                grunt.log.writeln( 'Output: ' + output );
            }
        },
        addfile: {
            commands: [
                'echo "testing" > /tmp/test.txt',
                'cat /tmp/test.txt'
            ],                
        },
        removefile: {                
            commands: [
                'rm -rf /tmp/test.txt',
                'cat /tmp/test.txt'
            ],
        }
    }
});
```

unfortunately the above configuration is not working (at least for me), I also did try leaving the original callbacks intact, but still no luck :(

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by [some minor amendment](https://github.com/webit4me/grunt-vagrant-ssh/commit/1f340791d911ed432e0edf65981ed8d956e8ef9c) on the plugin.

A [pull requires](https://github.com/carldanley/grunt-vagrant-ssh/pull/2) has been made and and is awaiting for merge by [Carl](https://github.com/carldanley) :)